# How to get the values of span tag in html using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My span tag consists of: `<span id="internal-source-marker_0.9510186333209276"><span>`

What I want to do is convert that into `<span><span>`

Basically, I want to get the check if span has an id value to it, and then remove it completely. I'm completely confused how to go about this. Should it be regex or beautiful soup?

The problem with regex is that I'm not sure how to replace a substring once it matches.

Maybe do a combination of beautiful soup and regex? (Not sure if that is a good and efficient idea.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply delete the attribute from the `attrib` mapping; assuming you have a reference to the `<span>` tag in a local variable `span`:

```
if span.has_key('id'):
    del span['id']
```

Demo:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<span id="internal-source-marker_0.9510186333209276"></span>')
>>> span = soup.find('span')
>>> span
<span id="internal-source-marker_0.9510186333209276"></span>
>>> if span.has_key('id'):
...     del span['id']
... 
>>> span
<span></span>
```

Comment: If I may ask, if such a task is done using regex, which one will be faster?

Comment: @Hick: that depends entirely on what *other* attributes might be present on the span tags. Regular expressions and HTML/XML can get really complex real fast.